# Find lines matching a pattern except those containing another pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code's regex syntax, is it possible to find all occurrences of a certain string, for e.g.

```
&$
```

except where there's another pattern, say the string `function(` in the same line, for example

```
function functionname(&$variable, ...)
```

?

This does not work for me:

```
(?!function).*\&\$
```

It simply yields *all* results, both lines with `function` in them, and without, as if I were doing a simple search for `&$`.

<strike>[VSCode's Regex help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)</strike> Visual Studio's help page seems to suggest that that's the way, but I can't seem to get it to work in any constellation in VS Code, so it seems the applications are using different notations.

Neither do a couple other notations work (I suppose from different regex flavours) that I've Googled around for.

Comment: That help page doesn't apply to VS Code. It applies to full VS. And VS Code appears to not use .NET Regexes.

Comment: @Eric indeed! That explains why it didn't work. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regexp may work:

```
^(?!.*function\().*(\&\$)
```

The `&$` is captured in the first group: `$1`

For the input:

```
a &$ b
a &$ function()
a &$ function()
function() &$ a
a function() &$ a
```

Only the `&$` on the first line will be matched using this regular expression.

The regular expression works by using a negative lookahead to ensure the line does not contain the string `function(`. This lookahead has to be pinned to the start of the line however, which is why the `.*` is required.. Also, this will only match one occurrence per line

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should work - but VSCode still catches *all* occurrences, including those with `function` in the beginning. Starting to think it might be a bug

Comment: Can you provide an example of text you are trying to match. I tested my simple example text in VSCode 1.8.1 on a mac and it does work (Added screenshot to post showing this)

Comment: An example of what it should not match: `function smarty_core_assign_smarty_interface($params, &$smarty)`  in my VS Code on MacOS, this *goes* get matched. Weird!

Comment: If you don't want that to be matched, remove the `\(` from `function\(`. That should fix things so that the line is no longer matched. The complete regexp would be: `^(?!.*function).*(\&\$)`

Comment: Argh! Yes! I never thought of putting the `.*` *inside* the negative lookahead. This works, thanks very much!